# How to enable loop dev access from LXC?

Tags: lxc

I added the following line to the LXC container's config file in order to enable access to loop dev. The LXC is running Ubuntu 12.04:

```
…
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = b 7:* rwm
…
```

However, the container fails to start after the change. Any ideas?

```
ubuntu@bpcluster1:~$ sudo lxc-start -n local-server-7 
lxc-start: write /sys/fs/cgroup/devices//lxc/local-server-7/devices.allow : Invalid argument
lxc-start: failed to setup the cgroups for 'local-server-7'
lxc-start: failed to setup the container
lxc-start: invalid sequence number 1. expected 2
lxc-start: failed to spawn 'local-server-7'
```